# I am getting errors from using try-except block to validate input

Tags: python, loops, random, try-except

I want to use the  **try-except** code block to notify the user not to insert **float** type values but **integers**.                                                               The code below doesn't throw an error but rather shuts down.
I guess they are logic errors on the **try-except** block.

```
userGuess = int(userGuess)
```

```
import random

MAX_GUESSES = 5  # max number of guesses allowed

MAX_RANGE = 20  # highest possible number

# show introductionpygame
print("welcome to my franchise guess number game")
print("guess any number between 1 and", MAX_RANGE)
print("you will have a range from", MAX_GUESSES, "guesses")

def playOneRound():
    # choose random target
    target = random.randrange(1, MAX_RANGE + 1)

    # guess counter
    guessCounter = 0

    # loop fovever
    while True:
        userGuess = input("take a guess:")

         #check for potential errors
         try:
             userGuess = int(userGuess)
         except: 
               print("sorry, you are only allowed to enter integers thanks!")



    # increment guess counter
    guessCounter = guessCounter + 1

    # if user's guess is correct, congratulate user, we're done
    if userGuess == target:
        print("you got it la")
        print("it only took you", guessCounter, "guess(es)")
        break
    elif userGuess < target:
        print("try again, your guess is too low.")
    else:
        print(" your guess was too high")

    # if reached max guesses, tell answer correct answer, were done
    if guessCounter == MAX_GUESSES:
        print(" you didnt get it in ", MAX_GUESSES, "guesses")
        print("the number was", target)
        break

    print("Thanks for playing ")

 # main code

 while True:
     playOneRound()  # call a function to play one round of the game
     goAgain = input("play again?(press ENTER to continue, or q to quit ):")
     if goAgain == "q":
         break
```

Comment: Doing `int(userGuess)` when `userGuess` is a float (e.g. `3.14`) will cast the float to an integer, and will not throw any error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use try-except block to validate the input, and use a while statement to prompt the user until a valid input in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096266/how-to-use-try-except-block-to-validate-the-input-and-use-a-while-statement-to)

Comment: If you're looking for specific debugging help, you should explain what behavior you're seeing and how it's different from what you want to be seeing.

Comment: Hi @Thesonter, what happens exactly when you run your program?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task can be split into two steps:

1. check that the input string can be converted into a number
2. check that this number is an integer

```py
while True:
    userGuess = input("take a guess: ")

    try:
        userGuess = float(userGuess)   # stuff like "asdf", "33ff" will raise a ValueError
        if userGuess.is_integer():     # this is False for 34.2
            userGuess = int(userGuess)
            break                      # an integer is found, leave the while loop
    except ValueError:
        pass                           # just try again

    print("sorry, you are only allowed to enter integers thanks!")
```

Comment: @Thesonter What does it mean "it didn't work"? Is there an error message? If yes, which one?

Comment: @Thesonter I have only checked the string to integer conversion. There might be other issues with your code, for example some wrong indentation.

Comment: thanks, might be. I'm still working on it.